# Windows 8.1 - Intermittent Network Issues (Browser Only)

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, browser

I have a Windows 8.1 machine at work which is getting on a bit but generally works fine. However, for the past few months or so, every few days I come in and I'm unable to open any websites.

Internet Explorer just gives my a generic failure message and Chrome says `ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED`.

Everything else works fine. I can ping hosts and perform DNS lookups. My email continues to work and all my SSH sessions, both local and remote, and still connected and usable. The only thing that refuses to work is web browsing.

However, to make the situation even more crazy, I can get the Chrome home screen up (reasonable as it's probably built in), but I can also search from that and view the results. I just can't then click on any result without an immediate connection error.

At the moment I have to just reboot which requires closing down everything I've kept open (usually ~8 applications, multiple ssh sessions, etc) and waiting 5 minutes to get back into Windows.

I've searched around but most results point to the Microsoft community sites which are generally the blind leading the blind. Pretty much the only answers I've found are to reboot, or to reset networking... followed by a reboot.

Anybody have any ideas on what I can try, or what might cause just browsers to give up when everything else is perfectly happy?

Comment: Any proxy configured? Have you tried disabling any security software? Any relevant events logged in the Windows event logs?

Comment: There's no web security software installed. Just tried event viewer but that seems to be giving me an `MMC could not create the snap-in error`.. Good old Microsoft

Comment: WOW. You've got bigger problems with your system if you cannot open the Event Viewer. Solving those may very well address this issue as well.

Comment: I'll probably just have to plan to re-install or replace this system and get by until then